# Default Values of mq_attr structure

Tags: c

We are setting the message queue attributes using

```
int mq_setattr(mqd_t mqdes, struct mq_attr *newattr,
                        struct mq_attr *oldattr);
```

where mq_attr is consisting of following fields :

```
struct mq_attr {
               long mq_flags;       /* Flags: 0 or O_NONBLOCK */
               long mq_maxmsg;      /* Max. # of messages on queue */
               long mq_msgsize;     /* Max. message size (bytes) */
               long mq_curmsgs;     /* # of messages currently in queue */
           };
```

My question at the time of creation if we have not set the attributes then what are values inside  mq_attr (default values) ?

Comment: You can use `mq_getattr` and see for yourself ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not initialize your `struct mq_attr`, but supply it when you do `mq_open`, the variables will have unspecified content. Meaning the mq_attr could have random values.

So

```
struct mq_attr attr; //Will be uninitialized -> bad thing
q = mq_open("/mqtest",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0660,&attr);
```

As always, in C, you need to initialize variables before using them.

You can pass NULL for the attribute to mq_open() to get the system defaults though.

You can learn the system defaults yourself. They're system dependent, and defaults might be tunable via sysctls, resource limits or similar.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mqueue.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct mq_attr attr;
    /*
    struct rlimit limit;
    if(getrlimit(RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE,&limit) == -1) {
        perror("getrlimit");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("RLIMIT_MSGQUEUE cur = %ld,max = %ld\n",(long)limit.rlim_cur,(long)limit.rlim_max);
    */

    mqd_t q = mq_open("/mqtest",O_RDWR|O_CREAT,0660,NULL);
    if(q == -1) {
        perror("mq_open");
        return 1;
    }
    if (mq_getattr(q, &attr) == -1) {
        perror("mq_getattr");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("mq_flags %ld\n",  attr.mq_flags);
    printf("mq_maxmsg %ld\n", attr.mq_maxmsg);
    printf("mq_msgsize %ld\n",attr.mq_msgsize);
    printf("mq_curmsgs %ld\n",attr.mq_curmsgs);
    mq_close(q);
    mq_unlink("/mqtest");
    return 0;
}
```

The commented out part can give you the rlimit for the max bytes in a queue on linux, set with e.g. the ulimit command.

Answer (score 1):

It depends by the compiler. However in C there are no default values for variables unlike Java or other languages so you can't have any expectation from what there are in your variables.

Comment: good practice is to memset just after creation, so all values are set to 0